# ffmpeg set filename pattern using python subprocess

Tags: python, regex, ffmpeg, subprocess

When running on command line, i use this code:

```
ffmpeg -i video-frame-%06d.png -c:v libx264 -vf "fps=25,format=yuv420p" out.mp4
```

But im trying to run it inside python script,and Im getting ***no such file or directory error***  and I think because of the formatting type for the image filename numerals `-%06d`

How can I concatenate or use the same file pattern I run in command line to use it in my python script

```
subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg -i dir/video-frame-%06d.png -c:v libx264 -vf "fps=25,format=yuv420p" out.mp4', shell=True])
```

> the sample image filename inside the folder are:
>
> 1. video-frame-00001.png
> 2. video-frame-00002.png
> 3. video-frame-00003.png

Comment: You should use the full path instead of relative path. Eg.: based on path of your Python file: `dir_of_imgs = os.path.join(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "dir")` and use this variable to define the path  of image: `os.path.join(dir_of_imgs, "video-frame-%06d.png")`

Comment: ffmpeg **wont** create the directory if it doesn't exist. And use the full path as mentioned by @milanbalazs.

Comment: @milanbalazs thanks that works :)

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: I have created an answer based on my comment. You can accept is if it solved your issue. Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated to the issue in the question, but you can remove `fps=25` as the default frame rate for the [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) is 25.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you want to run subprocess you have 2 options:

- one line command and use shell=True which is not recommended.
- or use a proper list.

try this:

```
cmd = 'ffmpeg -i dir/video-frame-%06d.png -c:v libx264 -vf "fps=25,format=yuv420p" out.mp4'
subprocess.run(cmd.split())
```

Comment: Hi, actually im using the shell=True param, I edited my post above. I tried your approach but I still get No such file 'dir/video-frame-%06d.png '

Answer (score 0):

You should use the full path instead of relative path. Eg.: based on path of your Python file:

```
dir_of_imgs = os.path.join(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "dir")
```

And use this variable to define the path of image:

```
img_path = os.path.join(dir_of_imgs, "video-frame-%06d.png")
```

It means your command should be something similar like that:

```
subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg -i {} -c:v libx264 -vf "fps=25,format=yuv420p" out.mp4'.format(img_path), shell=True])
```

**NOTE:**

Of course, probably your image files are in different folder but you can use the path of your Python file as a reference (as I show above).